# How to get data to string/int from ListBox ( ListBoxItems) Windows Universal

Tags: c#, listbox, win-universal-app

I hope no one already asked question like this before, I did a little research but non of answers worked for me, so I decided to ask it myself.
I'm making an simple app where user have to chose few options from the list, I already made ListBox and list of items.

```
<ListBox x:Name="Continent">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Europe" Foreground="White" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Africa" Foreground="White"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Asia" Foreground="White"/>
</ ListBox>
```

I'm quite new to Windows Universal Platform so I hope I done it right.

Anyway, now I would like, after user press "forward" button collect that data to an STRING for example. I tried with:

```
string selected = Continent.SelectedItem.Content;
```

and

```
string selected = Continent.SelectedItems[0].Content;
```

I also tried to add "text" value but it doesn't let.

Does anyone know how to do that? What's the most simple way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Content.ToString()`

Comment: `string selected = CELINA.SelectedItem.Content.ToString();` I did, thanks but it dosen't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not a good idea to use the content of your listboxitem. These controls have specific property to contain logic data and it's called 'tag'. You can put everything you want in it like complex objects and have a different display (content) value.

So you have to change your xaml to this :

```
<ListBox x:Name="Continent">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Europe" Foreground="White" Tag="europe" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Africa" Foreground="White" Tag="africa"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Asia" Foreground="White" Tag="asia"/>
</ListBox>
```

and your code-behind to this :

```
foreach (ListBoxItem selectedItem in Continent.SelectedItems)
{
  var continentTag = selectedItem?.Tag as string;
  if (continentTag != null)
  {
    //Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: In general, yes you can use Tag to store arbitrary data.  In your example you are casting the Tag to a string which is the same for my solution below where you cast the Content to string which was @Laurent Resman's original ask.  Additionally your solution requires typing in the string 2 times for each ListBoxItem.  For such a trivial use case, why have such overhead?

Comment: The question was about a trivial case but my answer is more global.I didn't said it was the perfect solution but it's way better than using only hard coded strings. You can with this solution translate your appliaction easily. In my example the Tag would stay the same and can be tested with a switch when the content can be localized. And to be perfectly honest, when you use Listbox you often use biding for ItemsSource and you can use the SelectedItems as complex objects.

Comment: Tag should have nothing to do with translating an app.  In that case one would use x:Uid, and make other changes.  As we both said, one would normally set content to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I think a reasonable answer here is to help you learn how to debug problems on your own, and discover things as you progress learning the platform.

The example you have is pretty simple.  Most of the time, the Content would be set to an instance of a class, like a Continent object.  However, what you have is fine, you just have to use the debugger to learn about the objects you are getting back.

For this: `var data = Continent.SelectedItem;`, you can see the following in the Immediate window:

```
data is ListBoxItem
true
(data as ListBoxItem).Content
"Africa"
(data as ListBoxItem).Content is string
true
((ListBoxItem)data).Content
"Africa"
```

Play around in the debugger when you get stuck, use the `Immediate window`, or look at `Locals` to discover the types being returned.

So your answer might be:

```
string selected = ((ListBoxItem)data).Content
```

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks, will try my best to figure out something